# p:confirm references wrong commandButton in dataGrid

Tags: primefaces, confirm

I am using confirm component of Primefaces 6.1. The problem is that I have several commandButton inside a dataGrid. When clicking on a commandButton, the confirmDialog is called but always with the first commandButton as the source.

Has anyone already encountered this issue ?

Many thanks.

Here is my xhtml code :

```
<p:dataGrid id="units" var="unit" value="#{programmeView.unites}" columns="3" layout="grid"
    paginator="false" styleClass="dataGridUnits" rowIndexVar="unitIndex">

    <p:panel styleClass="panelUnite">

        <p:commandLink value="#{unit.nom}" action="#{uniteView.loadPage(unit.id)}" ajax="false" />
        <p:commandButton id="deleteUnitBtn" styleClass="deleteButton" icon="fa fa-close"
                         actionListener="#{programmeView.deleteUnite(unit)}" update="units">
            <p:confirm header="#{props.deleteUnit}" message="#{props.deleteUnitConfirmMsg}" icon="fa fa-warning"
                               disabled="#{unit.systemes.isEmpty()}" />
        </p:commandButton>
            <p:tooltip for="deleteUnitBtn" value="#{props.deleteUnit}" position="top"/>

    </p:panel>

</p:dataGrid>
```

Comment: Sure you're using 6.1? This should have been fixed in 5.2.5: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/383 . Try ui:repeat instead of p:dataGrid, would it work? There are minor behavioral differences between iterative components...

Comment: Yes I'm sure using version 6.1. Thanks for the answer I'm gonna try this.